# Make a table for every user that signs up (Is it practical?)

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a authentication system for my C# apps, the authentication system is in PHP. It has users and it works perfectly right now for one person, such as myself. I can add my own customers, set their permissions, update my program, and do much more.

But...

I want it to work so that I can have users sign up with a developer account from which they can control their own customers. But the problem is, with just my account I already have three tables. (customers, files, and global)

So should I make a whole new table for every customer? Or should I just shove them all in one huge table, with a column stating the ID of their parent developer.

I really hope this was clear enough...

If you're still confused here's some pics which may help
(This is the three tables I need for just my developer account)

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

(Don't worry these are not my actual users passwords... I'm still working on the website, it's all example stuff now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them all in one table with an ID linking them to the parent / any other information you need to store.

You could even have a customer type column as well if you need to differentiate.

Either way, having a new table for each user is not the right way.

EDIT: If you are worried about the size of the table then don't be. As long as you implement correct [indexing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql%20indexing&oq=mysql%20indexing&aqs=chrome.0.57l2j60l4.1634&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) then accessing this information won't be a problem. MySQL can handle millions of records in a table.

Comment: MySQL tables can handle millions of records, I don' think you will have a problem. I will update my post to include some information.

Comment: s/millions/billions or more

Comment: @Patashu - My experience has only ever been in the millions (up to about 25 million records) so didn't want to overdo my respect for MySQL DBs :) If it can handle billions, great!

Answer (score 2):

"I want it to work so that I can have users sign up with a developer account from which they can control their own customers."

So, you have a one to many relationship.

A table of users...

And a table of customers, who have a foreign key referencing user.

That's two tables. If you think you need to make new tables for every user, or any similar idea like that, you are almost certainly wrong.